# Jtable content is visible through different tab

Tags: java, swing, jtable, opacity

I have JTabbedPane with 4 tabs. JtabbedPane is situated on a JLayeredPane. 1st and 4th tab contain JTable with custom models. Each of the tables is being refreshed every 5-10 seconds.
When 1st tab is active, and JTable on 4th has just finished refreshing, I can see content of the 4th on the 1st. Look at the screenshot. [image]
When I click on the other tab, or minimize window, that strange effect is gone. Till the next refresh of that table on 4th tab.
 Refreshing is done using Future<> object.
I used Swing GUI builder in Netbeans, so I have huge amount of code. Would post any piece which could be useful.

I tried to revalidate jTabbedPane, is had no effect. Both tables and jScrollPanes has opaque property set to true. So I tried to use SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). It helped a little bit - now first content update goes well, but later - the same problem.
2nd table model has method to update it's content

```
public void setData(LinkedList<Object[]> __rows) {   
    NewDevsTableModel.__rows = __rows;
    fireTableDataChanged();
}
```

It is used here (*I added SwingUtilities here*)

```
static class checkNew implements Callable<Boolean> {

@Override
public Boolean call() {
    ServiceMessage sm = ServiceMessage.getNewList();

    try {
        connect();
        os.write(sm.serialize());
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            if (is.available() > 0) {
                break;
            }

            if (i == 9) {
                disconnect();
                return false;
            }
        }

        byte[] actByte = new byte[is.available()];
        is.read(actByte);
        try {
            sm = ServiceMessage.Deserialize(actByte);   //may be there are no new devices
            if (sm.getType() == ServiceMessageType.NODATA) {
                MainWindow.jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(3, false);
                if (MainWindow.jTabbedPane1.getSelectedIndex() == 3) {
                    MainWindow.jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(0);
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;   //wrong answer type
            }
        } catch (ClassCastException | StreamCorruptedException e) {
            //remember selection and scroll
            final int scroll = MainWindow.jScrollPane3.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
            final int[] rows = MainWindow.newDevsTable.getSelectedRows();

            int col = MainWindow.devicesTable.getSelectedColumn();

            String[] parts = new String(actByte).split("\n");
            final LinkedList<Object[]> l = new LinkedList();
            for (int i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
                String[] dev = parts[i].split(";", -1);
                String descr = dev[2];
                boolean iptype = (!dev[3].equals("-"));
                String address = dev[4];
                boolean atmtype = (dev[5].equals("+"));


                if (MainWindow.newDevsTable.getRowCount() >= (i+1)) {
                    if ((MainWindow.newDevsTable.getValueAt(i, 4) != null) && !MainWindow.newDevsTable.getValueAt(i, 4).equals("")) {
                        descr = MainWindow.newDevsTable.getValueAt(i, 4).toString();
                    }
                }
                Object[] o = {dev[0], dev[1], MainWindow.language[180], MainWindow.language[4], descr, iptype, address, atmtype}; 
                l.add(o);
            }

            if (!l.isEmpty()) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        MainWindow.newDevsPanel.setVisible(true);
                        MainWindow.jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(3, true);
                        ((NewDevsTableModel)MainWindow.newDevsTable.getModel()).setData(l);   
                        ButtonColumn buttonColumn = new ButtonColumn(MainWindow.newDevsTable, addAction, 2, true);
                        buttonColumn = new ButtonColumn(MainWindow.newDevsTable, rejAction, 3, false);
                        //put selection back
                        for (int i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
                            MainWindow.newDevsTable.addRowSelectionInterval(rows[i], rows[i]);
                        }
                        MainWindow.jScrollPane3.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scroll);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                MainWindow.jTabbedPane1.setEnabledAt(3, false);
                if (MainWindow.jTabbedPane1.getSelectedIndex() == 3) {
                    MainWindow.jTabbedPane1.setSelectedIndex(0);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        disconnect();              
        return false;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

I submit the task this way

```
public static Future<Boolean> checkNewDevices() {        
    final Future<Boolean> task;        
    task = service.submit(new checkNew());
    return task;
}
```

To refresh automatically I use separate thread

```
public class CheckNewPassThread extends Thread {
int pause = 10000;

@Override
public void run() {
    for (;;) {
        HostConnection.checkNewDevices();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(pause);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
}
}
```

Which is started when the window is opened

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
    HostConnection.getData();        
    HostConnection.getDeviceAddress();
    RefreshData refreshThread = new RefreshData();
    refreshThread.start();
    new CheckNewPassThread().start();

}
```

Comment: again (like as for previous question) no idea, for why reason is there JLayeredPane, are you tried with placing JTabbedPane directly to the JFrame

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I need a jLayeredPane to place a combobox on the right upper corner of jTabbedPane

Comment: I also tried to add JTabbedPane directly, and ensured that I set data to the table in EDT by calling .isEventDispatchedThread()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, the problem was in calling jTabbedPane.setEnabledAt(3, true) to already enabled tab. Swing is fascinating